# "document.getElementbyId" isn't working for me

Tags: html, css

I have a button in my page

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('donation').style.visibility='visible'">Support</button>
```

That I want to have linked to making a hidden div (donation) visible. I'm not sure if the getElementById works with divs, but I couldn't find out either, because when I changed the Id to h1, with a simple color change for style, it didn't work either. 
Is there a problem with my button or syntax?

Comment: You could just run `document.getElementById('donation')` in your favorite browser's developer tool console and see what it returns, then take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still work this with an inline onclick.

Andrei is correct about the id needing to be an individual.

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('donation').style.visibility='visible'">Support</button>
<div style="background-color: gray; width: 50px; height: 50px; visibility: hidden;" id="donation"></div>
```

Technically though, it's better to keep your css and javascript in the head tag or outside of the html.

Comment: Unless you're doing feature detection or something similar load JS right before `</body>`, not in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `document.getElementById('donation')` to return a `DOM` element this condition would need to be true

- there should be one `html` element ***and only one*** with `id="donation"` in your page. For example: `<div id="donation"></div>`

It's possible that your function works flawlessly (you can easily tell if it is by looking at your browser `console` after you pushed the button) but your element would still remain not visible. For example, if its `display` property is set to `none`. There are many possible reasons why an element might not be rendered by the browser. The fastest way to pinpoint the reason would be for you to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example (using the <kbd><></kbd> button) where we could experience the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I think separating the codes will keep things clearer and readable.

```
<button id="donation_btn">Support</button>
```

The javascript

```
function enableDonation( button, donationElement ) {

    // check if the button is defined
    if ( button != undefined 
    && button != null ) {

        button.addEventListener( "click", function () {
            donationElement.style.display = "block";
        });
}

 // execute the code on document load
window.addEventListener( "load", function () {

    enableDonation( 
        document.getElementById( "donation_btn" ), 
        document.getElementById( "donation" )
    );

});
```